# Спец.символы не отображаются

Tags: html

[image: Скрин клиента]

У заказчика почему то вместо спец.символа рубля, что я указал в верстке, стоит что то похожее на чекбоксы. Как видите, использует он хром. Я проверил у себя и в хроме и в мозиле. У меня все как надо. Не пойму в чем проблема.[image: Мой скрин]

Вот, собственно, код этих блоков:

```
                            <div class="product">
                            <img class="discount" src="img/discount.png">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/product1.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <p class="product-title">
                            <a href="#">Шляпная коробка</a>
                            </p>
                            <p class="product-desc">диаметр 33 см, высота 40 см</p>
                            <p class="product-price">250&#8381;</p>
                            <div class="buttom_items">
                                <div class="more_info">
                                    <a href="#">Подробнее  ></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="v_korziny">
                                    <img src="img/cart.png">
                                    <a href="#">В корзину</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Вы уверены? У меня просто все отлично работает...

Comment: Смею предположить, что шрифт у заказчика не имеет знака рубля. Где и какие подключаются шрифты?

Comment: Пак робото шрифтов. В отдельном фале fonts.css, а этот файл уже в начале index.html, как положено.

Comment: ещё раз проверьте, как подхватываются шрифты - очевидно же, что на скриншотах шрифты разные. У заказчика дефолтный шрифт без поддержки рубля.

Comment: Шрифт тот же. Вас, видимо, смутило различие в шрифтах в других элементах сайта в первом и во втором скриншотах. Это правки, которые я внес. Ничего более.

Comment: Меня смутило то, что число отображается Roboto, а знак рубля неизвестным шрифтом с засечками.

Comment: у заказчика знак рубля показывается шрифтом, не имеющим знака рубля. Знак рубля официально утвержден 11 декабря 2013  года, может у вашего заказчика шрифт древнее.